# Sorting array function over JSON loops like crazy

Tags: json, loops, infinite

so I'm trying to deal with a function but it's looping like crazy and I can't figure out why.

Basically, I want to loop over a json file, retrieve every "average" value and sort it in a new array, so when I call the function ranking(countries[iso].average), it returns the position in the array.

It's actually working but the json file is way bigger, and when I console.log(rank) in the loop, it returns more than 27K messages.

```js
ranking = (n) => { 
    var rank = [];
    if (n) {
        for (let iso in countries) {
            var newvar = countries[iso].average;            
            rank.push(newvar);
            rank.sort(function(a, b) {
                return b - a;
            });         
        }
        return rank.indexOf(n) + 1   
    }
};
```

```html
{"countries":{"US":{"name":"United States of America","ranking":"","average":13.12,"flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/usa.svg","altNames":["US","USA"],"reports":1302,"cases":0,"deaths":299692,"recovered":23232,"lat":38,"lng":-97,"deltaCases":2,"deltaDeaths":3,"deltaRecovered":0,"casesPerOneMillion":2,"deathsPerOneMillion":903,"totalTests":22323,"testsPerOneMillion":3434,"population":345},"IN":{"name":"India","ranking":"","average":10.22,"flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/ind.svg","altNames":["IN","Bhārat"],"reports":1016,"cases":9796992,"deaths":142222,"recovered":9290834,"lat":20,"lng":77,"deltaCases":null,"deltaDeaths":null,"deltaRecovered":646,"casesPerOneMillion":7068,"deathsPerOneMillion":103,"totalTests":151632223,"testsPerOneMillion":109402,"population":1295210000},"RU":{"name":"Russian Federation","ranking":"","average":13.21,"flag":"https://restcountries.eu/data/rus.svg","altNames":["RU","Rossiya"],"reports":1321,"cases":2597711,"deaths":45893,"recovered":2059840,"lat":60,"lng":100,"deltaCases":28585,"deltaDeaths":613,"deltaRecovered":26171,"casesPerOneMillion":17797,"deathsPerOneMillion":314,"totalTests":81564365,"testsPerOneMillion":558804,"population":146599183}}}
```

Thanks for any help on this

Comment: Why are you sorting after every insertion?

Comment: It looks like your entire code is just `Object.values(countries).map(({average}) => average).sort((a, b) => b - a).indexOf(n)`.

Comment: I see but I used to call the function like this : raking(countries[iso].average), to retrieve the average of the country I'm clicking. SO here I don't see what "n" equal to. I've been thinking too much(help me) :/

Comment: It's really not clear what you're after here, because that description bears little resemblance to the code posted. If you click on a country in the UI then you have it's *name*. Why are you iterating (and sorting, and re-sorting) anything at all? If you just want the ranking then you create a hash, one time, like so: `const rankings = Object.entries(data.countries).sort(([nameA, itemA], [nameB, itemB]) => itemA.average - itemB.average).reduce((acc, [countryName], i) => (acc[countryName] = i + 1, acc), {});` Then it's just `rankings[countryName]` to get the rank.

Comment: Unless you expect the data to change, there's no need to re-compute it again and again. And there's certainly no need to sort it more than once.

Comment: Might be out of my league I think. It's for this fun project : allsizesmatter.com. You can see the ranking works, but have a look in the console, it's crazy.

Comment: Thanks anyway dude, it's still working fine, but I can hear my computer getting hot while loading the website ahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you may be trying to do is sort by the field called average for countries in the iso. So you have some lookup called `countries` and there are ISOs there like I imagine: `'US'`. Then Rank is an array of all these countries.

The problem I see is that you have sort happening within the for loop.

The way you explained the problem seems like 2 different steps. One retrieve the average, then AFTER that sort by the average.

If really all you want is the averages in the array: you can do like

```
const averages = Object.values(countries).map(country => country.average)
```

That single step will get you all the averages into a single array.

Then next you can sort using the same function you posted. (The key is to brake that into a second loop not a nested loop:

averages.sort((a, b) => b - a)
// now sorted

But in case you wanted to keep the rest of the data you can do that pretty easily as well:

Something more like:

```
const countriesSortedByAverage = Object.values(countries).sort((a, b) => b.average - a.average)
```

If you really need the ISO you can also do the same with `Object.entries` but it might be even easier to provide the `iso` inside the country Object.

To determine the rank for all countries you can easily add that to (if you wanted) and have that be the principal country Object:

```
const RANKED_LIST_OF_COUNT = countriesSortedByAverage.map((countryObj, rank) => ({ ...countryObj, rank }))
```

If you want to further restore it to the CountriesByISO object:

```
const COUNTRIES_BY_ISO_WITH_RANK = Object.assign({}, ...RANKED_LIST_OF_COUNT.map(country => ({ [country.ISO]: country}))
)
```

Comment: did this seem to solve the issue for you? did I understand the needs of the code at least?

Comment: I see you may have changed the question a little bit, I still want to help you if you're having a problem.
Does this apply to the scenario:
1. User clicks on View ranked list of countries?
2. User views all countries ranked Descending (Large->Small)
If the data looks like: 
const countries = {
US: { average: 5.6},
UK: { average: 5.4}
},
and what you want it to be is:
[{ country: 'US', average: 5.6}, {country: 'US', average: 5.4 }]
Does this not achieve that?

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. It's closer to case 1. Actually you can see it in action here : www.allsizesmatter.com : When you click on a country, it loop through the JSON api file, check if it has "average" value. Then it creates an array to sort theses values. When you click on a country, it return the indexOf the value. Does it make sense ? It's actually working, but the function I've created 'ranking()' creates a crazy loop.

Comment: script file visible in console - wp-content - > plugins -> myearth.js. I'm using -> 'ranking(countries[iso].average)' to retrieve the value of the country that has been clicked

Comment: I see: so you want the rank of that specific country to be there when you click on that component.

Comment: Yes, it works, but somehow looping too much

Comment: So why not use my solution in one spot: so now you have the ranked list (where every country object is in the ranked list). Then when a user clicks on a specific country: you go to the global window Object: `window.RANKED_LIST_OF_COUNTRIES.findIndex((current) => current.country === CountryClicked)`

Comment: I tried to use what you explained in you answer, but did not manage so far...

Comment: because I don't know how to go from this : ranking = (n) => { 
            var rank = [];
            if(n){
            for (let iso in countries) {
                var newvar = countries[iso].average;            
                    rank.push(newvar);
                    console.log(rank + 'for loop before sorting')           
          }
          rank.sort(function(a, b) {
            return b - a;
          });       
          return rank.indexOf(n) + 1 
          
        }
        };  
to you answer :/

Comment: But so far I'm using a function to retrieve the rank 'ranking(countries[iso].average)'. using 'COUNTRIES_BY_ISO_WITH_RANK' instead in my code doesn't do so far. Right now I want my function to stop looping like crazy

Comment: once you've set `window.RANKED_LIST_OF_COUNTRIES` your new function `getRankOfCountry` can look like: `function getRankOfCountry(country) { return window.RANKED_LIST_OF_COUNTRIES.findIndex(current) => current.country === CountryClicked) + 1 }`. You add +1 because otherwise "First" place is `0` ranked.